# how to keep storage with GetStorage flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

trying to save some data using GetSorage in flutter app but when i leave the app and come back again all the storage is deleted.
this is how i get my data from db

```
  final box = GetStorage();
  List<Mesure> measures = [];

if (box.hasData("measures")) {
  List<dynamic> records = box.read("measures");
  if (records is Map<String, dynamic>) {
    for (var element in records) {
      measures.add(Mesure.fromJson(element));
    }
  } else if (records is List<Mesure>) {
    measures = records;
  }
}
```

and this how i update it when i have some thing to change

```
 setState(() {
  widget.mesure.sampleNumber = result.rawContent;
  measures.removeWhere((Mesure measure) => measure.id == widget.mesure.id);
  measures.add(Mesure.fromJson(widget.mesure.toJson()));
  box.write("measures", measures);
});
```

Comment: is it because u didn't initialize the key measure with null   value for the first time ?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to access data upon app restart (simplified):

```dart
main() async {
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(App());
}
```

```dart
var storage = GetStorage('myStorageName');

doWrite(String key, String value) async {
  await storage.write(key, value);
}

String? read(String key) {
  return storage.read(key);
}
```

https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage